# Typeahead for large database

Tags: javascript, json, autocomplete, typeahead

there is 100.000 records in my database.

```
ID - BOOK (text)
1  - book1
2  - good book
3  - bad book
```

etc.

Than, I want to make a typeahead input for this.
But which plugin I should use or how to use, I don't know.

```
$('#search').typeahead({
    source: function (query, process) {
        // what should I do here?
    }
});
```